# LibGit2Sharp.Core.NativeMethods exception upon Cloning repository on UiPath Studio

Tags: git, gitlab, uipath, uipath-studio, uipath-api

[image: LibGit2Sharp.Core.NativeMethods exception]

This error still appears after trying to get the repository from gitlab and to:

1. deleting UiPath folder on these paths

   - C:\ProgramData
   - C:\ProgramFiles
   - C:\ProgramFiles (x86)
   - C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local
2. re-install the UiPath Studio Pro - Community ver 2020.4.1

As of the moment I use git-bash but it costs much time than using the source control on UiPath Studio which I can't also use.

Here's the log message:

```
Error: System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'LibGit2Sharp.Core.NativeMethods' threw an exception. --->
System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'git2-572e4d8': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
   at LibGit2Sharp.Core.NativeMethods.git_libgit2_init()
   at LibGit2Sharp.Core.NativeMethods.InitializeNativeLibrary()
   at LibGit2Sharp.Core.NativeMethods..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at LibGit2Sharp.Core.NativeMethods.git_clone(git_repository*& repo, String origin_url, FilePath workdir_path, GitCloneOptions& opts)
   at LibGit2Sharp.Core.Proxy.git_clone(String url, String workdir, GitCloneOptions& opts)
   at LibGit2Sharp.Repository.Clone(String sourceUrl, String workdirPath, CloneOptions options)
   at UiPath.Studio.Plugin.Git.Wrappers.RepositoryInit.Clone(String sourceUrl, String workdirPath, CloneOptions options)
   at UiPath.Studio.Plugin.Git.Services.Core.CloneService.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.<CheckoutCore>b__0()
   at UiPath.Studio.Plugin.Git.Services.UI.UiAuthenticationSession.Execute[T](ExecuteArgs`1 args)
   at UiPath.Studio.Plugin.Git.Services.Core.CloneService.CheckoutCore(String uri, String localFolder, IAuthenticationSession authenticationSession)
   at UiPath.Studio.Plugin.Git.Services.Core.CloneService.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<Checkout>b__0()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at UiPath.Studio.Plugin.Git.Services.Core.CloneService.<Checkout>d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at UiPath.Studio.Plugin.Git.Services.UI.CheckOutUiService.<CheckOut_ExecuteInternal>d__16.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at UiPath.Studio.SourceControl.Shared.Services.UI.BaseCheckOutUiService`1.<CheckOut_Execute>d__25.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at UiPath.Studio.SourceControl.Shared.Services.UI.BaseCheckOutUiService`1.<<get_CheckOutCommand>b__11_0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at UiPath.Studio.Shared.MVVM.Commands.TaskCommand`3.<Execute>d__32.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.<>c.<ThrowAsync>b__6_0(Object state)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(Object state)
   at MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.CallbackWrapper(Object obj)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.Run(CulturePreservingExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Window.ShowHelper(Object booleanBox)
   at System.Windows.Window.Show()
   at System.Windows.Window.ShowDialog()
   at UiPath.Studio.Shell.ShellApplication.StudioShellApplication.HandleRunApplication()
   at UiPath.Studio.Core.StudioApplication.StudioApplication.<PostLicenseInitAsync>d__16.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at UiPath.Studio.Shell.ShellApplication.StudioShellApplication.<HandleAquireLicense>d__14.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at UiPath.Studio.Shell.ShellApplication.StudioShellApplication.<OnTempWindowLoaded>d__13.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.<>c.<ThrowAsync>b__6_0(Object state)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(Object state)
   at MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.CallbackWrapper(Object obj)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.Run(CulturePreservingExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run(Window window)
   at UiPath.Studio.Shell.ShellApplication.StudioShellApplication.HandleBeforeLicensingInit()
   at UiPath.Studio.Core.StudioApplication.StudioApplication.StartApplication()
   at UiPath.Studio.Core.StudioApplication.StudioApplication.Start(String[] args), HResult -2146233036
```

Comment: Which UiPath Studio version is used?

Comment: Community Edition version 2020.4.1 - stable

Comment: I would recommend to not use Git of UiPath Studio. It's just too unstable. Better use external tools like TortoiseGit. That's a proper visual Git Client that I use without issues. But to your issue. Did you use Git on UiPath Studio?

Comment: Can you show the details of the exception?  It will help to determine the actual cause

Comment: @kwoxer yes I'm using external tools as of the moment. I was using Git UiPath Studio before it happened

Comment: hi @Dave I've added the log message above. Hope it'll help

Answer (score 0):

uninstall `VS 2019 community` ed. Then I downgrade to `VS 2017 community` ed.
I checkout the branches and it fixed my problem, but don't know how it directly affects the cloning of git repo.

Comment: That more sounds to me that the uninstallation killed the hidden Git folder. So if it appears again. Try to delete the hidden folder. And then close the repo again.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and i have resolved by installing this https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53587
Just download and install the above pack and then restart your p-c and try again